# Remove or change the calendar icon from angular material datepicker

Tags: angularjs, svg, datepicker, angular-material

I was using [`angular material`](https://material.angularjs.org). I find it very cool, well designed and user friendly.
 I was trying to  change or remove the calendar `icon` on `datepicker` directive.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ></md-datepicker>
```

The default icon is very good but i want to skip the icon in some case. well i can use svg icon using md-icon like this

```
 <md-icon md-svg-src="calendar.svg"></md-icon>
```

Here is my [sample plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqAsAQ1PDUZ2nU5xo4Q0?p=preview). Suggest me some idea to change/remove the default icon on datepicker.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Angular Material 1.1.0 has a solution, although it seems undocumented.

From angular-material/modules/js/datepicker/datepicker.js:

```
* @param {String=} md-hide-icons Determines which datepicker icons should be hidden. Note that this may cause the
* datepicker to not align properly with other components. **Use at your own risk.** Possible values are:
* * `"all"` - Hides all icons.
* * `"calendar"` - Only hides the calendar icon.
* * `"triangle"` - Only hides the triangle icon.
```

Usage:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myModel" md-hide-icons="calendar"></md-datepicker>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me. Just to simplify - all you need to do is pass in : 
md-hide-icons="all" - To hide both caret and calendar icon
md-hide-icons="calendar" - To hide only calendar icon
md-hide-icons="triangle" - To hide only caret icon

Answer (score 7):

The original question was how to "to change or remove the calendar icon on datepicker directive."?

I just know how to remove it.

You can remove the calendar icon by simply putting the following in a CSS file and adding it to your page:

```css
.md-datepicker-button {
    display: none !important;   
}

.md-datepicker-input-container {
    margin-left: 0 !important;    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better [solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbe2g2oeVillXO3QJUm8?p=preview).

1. create a `button` with another icon and place it in the same div with datepicker

   ```
   <div flex=40>
        <md-icon md-svg-src="calendar.svg"></md-icon>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ></md-datepicker>
   </div>
   ```
2. set the `button` postion to cover the orginal `datepicker` icon

   ```
   <div flex=40>
        <md-icon style="position:absolute;margin-top:15px; left:20px" md-svg-src="calendar.svg"></md-icon>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ></md-datepicker>
   </div>
   ```
3. set the the original `datepicker` icon to apparent.

   ```
   .md-datepicker md-icon {color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;}
   .md-datepicker-open .md-datepicker-calendar-icon {fill:rgba(0,0,0,0)}
   ```

Comment: @Jigs in your case, click on the icon cannot trigger the datepicker.  I tried, but the code `ng-click="ctrl.openCalendarPane($event)` doesn't work and will cause some error.    This solution can avoid it.

Comment: can you made a plunker of this ?

Comment: This is a poor solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
.md-datepicker-button.md-icon-button {
  display: none;
}
```

This one works for me.

Answer (score 0):

They do not provide an API option for specifying the icon, and as you can see from [datepicker template](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/datepicker/datePicker.js#L58).

The `md-calendar` icon is hard-coded inside the template. I suggest creating yourself a directive based from theirs and change it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Ralph is kind of complex which is  i have to create a new `directive` from their `directive`. I found a simple solution to this problem. The template of this `md-calendar` is using a `button` with an `icon` like this

```
         <md-button class="md-datepicker-button md-icon-button" type="button" 
              tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" 
              ng-click="ctrl.openCalendarPane($event)"> 
            <md-icon class="md-datepicker-calendar-icon" md-svg-icon="md-  calendar">
           </md-icon> 
          </md-button>
```

So i change the css of class `md-datepicker-button`and hide the `button`

```
.calendarDiv .md-datepicker-button{
 display: none;
}
```

and use another custom `icon` like this

```
<md-icon md-svg-src="calendar.svg"></md-icon>
```

The `icon` isn't functional as default `icon`but this would solve my problem .

This is my [sample solution plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqAsAQ1PDUZ2nU5xo4Q0?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can change and hide the icon in the following way:

First give the md-datepicker an id (or class to target more then one):

```
<md-datepicker id="my-date-picker"></md-datepicker>
```

Then you can target the icon in css and change the color, size, display etc:

`#my-date-picker .md-datepicker-calendar-icon {
    color: green;
    display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

**md-datepicker** *now* has a configuration attribute for hiding the icons. From the docs:

**md-hide-icons**   String
Determines which datepicker icons should be hidden. Note that this may cause the datepicker to not align properly with other components. Use at your own risk. Possible values are:

- "all" - Hides all icons.
- "calendar" - Only hides the calendar icon.
- "triangle" - Only hides the triangle icon.

Using CSS to override the default triangle icon (I want the calendar icon on the right) using a custom theme with the FontAwesome icon

```css
/* override md material*/
.md-custom-theme .md-datepicker-input-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
.md-custom-theme .md-datepicker-expand-triangle {
  border:none;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  top: 6px;
  right:0;
}
.md-custom-theme .md-datepicker-expand-triangle:before {
  content: "\f073";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove date-picker toggle for icon remove(I am using latest files of Angular Material)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" (click)="from_date.open()">
                    <mat-label>From Date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="from_date">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="from_date"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #from_date></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

Remove this line

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="from_date"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mat-icon in combination with mat-datepicker-toggle to change the calendar icon of mat-datepicker

```
<input [matDatepicker]="basicDatepicker">
<mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="basicDatepicker">
  <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>
      mouse
  </mat-icon>
</mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #basicDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
```

instead if mouse you can use your costume icon by:

```
<mat-icon fontIcon="myCustomIcon"> </mat-icon>
```

For reference : https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/datepicker/

Answer (score -1):

I know how to remove it.

Just copy and paste the code below in your css

```
div.layout-align-start-start.layout-row>.md-icon-button.md-button.md-ink-ripple:not(.md-raised){
display: none;}
```